# Changed to Nvidia xorg driver - now I have less temperature sensors?

Tags: xorg, nvidia, temperature, sensors, nouveau

I've just installed Debian Wheezy 7.5 on a Toshiba Satellite P100 laptop.

By default, X was using the nouveau graphics driver.  While this was still installed, I was getting 6 different temperature readings from lm-sensors.  Here's an example of the output, I had:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +50.0°C  (crit = +104.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +52.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +52.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

lm99-i2c-2-4c
Adapter: nouveau-0000:01:00.0-2
temp1:        +49.0°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high = +85.0°C)
                       (crit = +85.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)
temp2:        +64.9°C  (low  = +16.0°C, high = +101.2°C)
                       (crit = +101.0°C, hyst = +91.0°C)

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +39.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +110.0°C)
```

However, the temperatures were much higher than above.  The lm99/nouveau temp2 was hitting 95c while the computer was idle.  And some others were in the 60c-70c range.   The laptop felt quite hot.

So I then installed the binary nvidia drivers hoping this might lower the temperature of the system.  However, now when I look at lm-sensors, I only get three readings:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +49.0°C  (crit = +104.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +51.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +51.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

I'm concerned that I can't see the extra readings I had before, so I can't be sure the system still isn't running hot.

Anybody got any ideas how I can check, or anything I can look at?

I've tried running the sensors-detect script, it added a couple of modules, but I still only get the three readings.

Thanks.